# How to send data after handoff from web page?

Tags: ios, swift, handoff

I have implemented handoff from a webpage into my app using this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]!) -> Void) -> Bool
```

I know you can send data from a mac app to an iOS app via userActivity or even a continuation stream. Is there a way to send data with the handoff from a webpage to a iOS app?